# Facebook share count - rate limit?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**CONTEXT**

I've added a share count call on a WordPress site using this code:

```
  foreach($url_list as $url){
    //Facebook call, returns json of shares of this url
     $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/".$url),true);
     $count_recipe = $count_recipe + ($json['shares']);
  }
```

I'm using it to get the share count for 10 different URL's, add them up and then display the sum to the user. I've read that the rate-limit for Graph API is 200 calls per user per hour ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting)).

**PROBLEM**

Since I'm not actually let people post to their own FB, I'm not sure if my calls will be treated as coming from different users (in which case I won't pass the rate limit), or from a single user (in which case, I will surely pass the rate limit). If the latter is the case, is there a way around it?

Comment: One user because you don't specify any access token. Just cache the value for a while

Comment: Thank you - that puts me in the right direction. I thought I would have to create an SQL table to hold that single value, didn't realize I could cache it across users.